# Unsuspend link on meta is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, per-site-meta, account-suspension

There is a broken markdown link when you click the "Mod" link on a suspended user's meta profile:

[image]

In case it's relevant, the link in the broken part has dashes in it (that is, the username contains spaces). However, this text doesn't function as a link even when the username doesn't contain spaces or punctuation.

---

For comparison, the link for "Contact user privately" works fine:

[image]

Note that the latter links to `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/message/create/<USERID>`; I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I can confirm that this still happens even if the username has no spaces or punctuation in it.

Comment: I wonder if its been broken for ages and no once noticed :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I can't think of a recent change that'd affect this and I only found this more or less by chance so... quite possibly it has been like this for a long time :P

Comment: I would be highly surprised if markdown works in their razor views at all.  I guess the dev meant `<a href="url here">main site</a>`

Comment: Yep, looks like this is still happening. I'll forward this to the relevant dev team.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a proper 'chuck it at the new guy' fix.

And as the new guy, I'm pleased to report that it's sorted - markdown *does* work in our templates, but this one had for some reason been set as a string. Go figure.

Comment: Thank you! As the new guy, can you also please change the tag on this question to [status-completed] instead of [status-review]? Thanks! :)

Comment: Certainly can - good catch, cheers!

Comment: Haha, well, welcome! Thanks for getting this fixed!